# jquery change image margin inside specific divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, margin

this is my code :

html

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="one">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the image margins only inside div class="one"
here is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {                  
  $(".one").each(function(){
        $("img").css("margin-top", 10 "px");
  });
});
```

this code ends up changing all the image margins, ...help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector `$("img")` matches *all* images, and so applies that `css` to them repeatedly, once for each `div.one`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                  
  $(".one img").css("margin-top", "10px");
});
```

*(I've also changed `10 "px"` to `"10px"`, but I assume that's a typo in the question.)*

`$(".one img")` uses a *descendant selector* to match all `img` elements that are descendants of elements with class `"one"`.

If you only want to match ones that are *direct children* (as in your example markup), use `>` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                  
  $(".one > img").css("margin-top", "10px");
  //      ^--- change is here
});
```

More about selectors:

- [Selectors Level 3 - W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
- [jQuery Selector Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: this answers my question.